# BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create resources using terraform, but suddenly I am getting following error.

```
│ Error: creating Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket
(stg-s3-bucket-v1): BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it. 
│   status code: 409, request id: TT9F89F53EBE2YX3, host id:
e3pShR/flx7fjm4Al/FsfOaR78lzlgumZIX9pbLLxQrIg1Hb0e1R2TqRUse6hisvF8hgSIqJl+U=
│   with aws_s3_bucket.stg_s3_bucket_v1,
│   on terraform.tf line 25, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "stg_s3_bucket_v1": 
│   25: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "stg_s3_bucket_v1" { 
│
```

I want to use that S3 bucket if already exists. Are there any way to do this?

Here is my tf

```
# main.tf
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-central-1"
}
    
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-0aea56f3589631913"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "Trackerie Stg"
  }
    
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
                sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
                sudo apt-get install -y apache2
                sudo systemctl start apache2
                # Additional setup steps for your Spring Boot application
                EOF
}
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "stg_s3_bucket_v1" {
  bucket = "stg-s3-bucket-v1"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "STG S3 Bucket"
  }

  force_destroy = true
}
    
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway" {
  name        = "Trackerie Stg"
}
    
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api_gateway_resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "stg"
}
    
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "api_gateway_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_gateway_resource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
    
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gateway_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_gateway_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gateway_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "HTTP_PROXY"
  uri                     = "https://${aws_instance.ec2_instance.private_ip}:8080/"
}
    
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_gateway_deployment" {
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_integration.api_gateway_integration]
  
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  stage_name  = "stg"
}
    
output "ec2_instance_public_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.ec2_instance.public_ip
}
    
output "s3_bucket_name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.stg_s3_bucket_v1.id
}
    
output "api_gateway_endpoint" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_gateway_deployment.invoke_url
}
```

Comment: You can import existing resources using `terraform import` eg `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.stg_s3_bucket_v1 stg-s3-bucket-v1`

Comment: It might be also that there is no state file.

Comment: Can you post the result of the command "terraform state list".  If the list of resources included in the state file does NOT include your bucket stg-s3-bucket-v1,  you may need to import it as advised by @jordanm.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can import the s3 bucket to the tfstate file
Once done, you can use the same in the terraform code.